# Как сделать анимацию при передвижении по 2 осям вместо 1?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ситуация следующая, писал код по гайду и при работе с аниматором заметил, что у автора гайда анимация проигрывалась и при передвижении по оси Y, хотя в коде он указал только X. Я начал пытаться исправить эту проблему, при добавлении к  if(moveInput.x == 0) y студия писала что float не содержит его, но в отдельности она его видела. Как совместить x и y в одном if?
Вот что пишет студия > Ошибка   CS1061  "float" не содержит определения "y", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "y", принимающий тип "float" в качестве первого аргумента

```
if(moveInput.x == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("IsRunning", false);

        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
        }
```

Comment: У вас нет `y` в коде, всегда показывайте тот код, о котором говорите, а не что-то другое. А вообще наверное так: `anim.SetBool("IsRunning", moveInput.x != 0 || moveInput.y != 0);`

Comment: Теперь анимация включается когда персонаж двигается по диагонали

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно скопировали код? Там `||`, а не `&&`.